# How to change date format miliseconds like this Mon Oct 09 16:06:27 WIB 2017

Tags: php

I try to convert time to my local time (Asia/Jakarta)

this is my Current Milliseconds : 1507539987576

i want convert to like this format : Mon Oct 09 16:06:27 WIB 2017

this is my code using php

```
    date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Jakarta");
    $now = new DateTime();
    $nowadays = date('Y-m-d');

    $time = round(microtime(true) * 1000);
    $seconds = $time / 1000;
    $currdate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $seconds);

    echo $currdate;
```

and the result like this : 2017-10-09 16:06:27

can someone tell me how to convert the time like this format : Mon Oct 09 16:06:27 WIB 2017

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) outlines all of the format characters. The string that you require to parse the date in the format you've indicated (i.e. *Mon Oct 09 16:06:27 WIB 2017*) is as follows:

```
date( 'D M d H:i:s T Y' );
```

We can break this down as follows:

- `D`: A textual representation of a day, three letters
- `M`: A short textual representation of a month, three letters
- `d`: Day of the month, 2 digits with leading zeros
- `H`: 24-hour format of an hour with leading zeros
- `i`: Minutes with leading zeros
- `s`: Seconds, with leading zeros
- `T`: Timezone abbreviation
- `Y`: A full numeric representation of a year, 4 digits

---

I also do not understand why you're working with microtime and then calculating the seconds. By default, `date()` will always use the current time, or you can simply use [`time()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) instead of your calculations.

Comment: aw thankyour sir ! thankyou very much !
btw how you know that?
im already googling and check php manual and still dont know the answer :(

Comment: @illuminarch See the table on the documentation page, it explains each digit. I have added a full explanation for each character to the answer.